# Adding the cell value to a formula for a range just uses the first value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

What I'm trying to do is only so I can easily do a find and replace in a subsequent step. Otherwise, there is no reason for doing this.

I'm trying to take the values of a cell range and put them in a formula. For example:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("<placeholder_value>","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
```

So if I have a table like the following:

```
| id | group  | formula |
| -- | ------ | ------- |
| 1  | GROUP1 |         |
| 2  | GROUP1 |         |
| 3  | GROUP1 |         |
| 4  | GROUP1 |         |
| 5  | GROUP1 |         |
| 6  | GROUP2 |         |
| 7  | GROUP2 |         |
| 8  | GROUP2 |         |
| 9  | GROUP2 |         |
| 10 | GROUP2 |         |
```

I'd like the formula for `id <=5` to be:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP1","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
```

I'd like the formula for `id >5` to be:

```
=VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP2","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
```

Then as I generate separate files for `GROUP1` and `GROUP2` I can find a replace in the `MASTER` with the actual document ID and link the documents via `VLOOKUP` such that updates in `GROUP1` and `GROUP2` are reflected in `MASTER`. **That is an oversimplified example.**

So what I've tried thus far is doing:

```
let placeholderRange = this.sheet.getRange(2, this.groupColumn, this.lastRow - 1, 1);
let formula = '=' + placeholderRange.getValue();
// let formula = '=' + placeholderRange.getValues(); 
// let formula = '=' + placeholderRange.getDisplayValue();
// let formula = '=' + placeholderRange.getDisplayValues();
formulaRange.setFormula(formula);
```

In the case of `.getValue()` and `.getDisplayValue()` it only uses the first value it finds, so it would put `GROUP1` in every formula instead of changing to `GROUP2` when it gets to those records.

In the case of `.getValues()` and `.getDisplayValues()`, it just adds an array of all the values in that range to the formula.

I can do what I'm after with a `for` loop, but trying to avoid that initially since that will slow the automation down.

Any suggestions for how to accomplish this?

Comment: Am I reading this correctly as the only problem being that you want a dynamic reference to a document, depending on the group?

Comment: Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your question, I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not useful, I apologize.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to convert the following situation by reducing the process cost.

  - From

    ```
      id  group   formula
      1   GROUP1
      2   GROUP1
      3   GROUP1
      4   GROUP1
      5   GROUP1
      6   GROUP2
      7   GROUP2
      8   GROUP2
      9   GROUP2
      10  GROUP2
    ```
  - To

    ```
      id  group   formula
      1   GROUP1  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP1","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
      2   GROUP1  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP1","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
      3   GROUP1  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP1","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
      4   GROUP1  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP1","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
      5   GROUP1  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP1","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
      6   GROUP2  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP2","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
      7   GROUP2  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP2","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
      8   GROUP2  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP2","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
      9   GROUP2  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP2","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
      10  GROUP2  =VLOOKUP($A2,IMPORTRANGE("GROUP2","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)
    ```

From your script, I supposed that your script might be created as a method in a Class. If my understanding is correct, how about the following modification?

#### From:

```
let placeholderRange = this.sheet.getRange(2, this.groupColumn, this.lastRow - 1, 1);
let formula = '=' + placeholderRange.getValue();
// let formula = '=' + placeholderRange.getValues(); 
// let formula = '=' + placeholderRange.getDisplayValue();
// let formula = '=' + placeholderRange.getDisplayValues();
formulaRange.setFormula(formula);
```

#### To:

```
const range = this.sheet.getRange(2, this.groupColumn, this.lastRow - 1, 1);
const formulas = range.getValues().map(([v]) => [`=VLOOKUP(\$A2,IMPORTRANGE("${v}","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)`]);
range.offset(0, 1, formulas.length, 1).setFormulas(formulas);
```

- In this modified script, when `this.groupColumn` is the column of "group", the formula of `=VLOOKUP(\$A2,IMPORTRANGE("${v}","Sheet!A:B"),2,0)` is created using the values of the column "group".

#### References:

- [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)
- [setFormulas(formulas)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setformulasformulas)